# "has no method 'getscript'" in Node.js server using Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, getscript

I have a server in Node.js and I use Express to make a web app.
My server (app.js) gets data from a form (by Ajax post method) and I want that it proceeds this data by using the code of another file (anotherfile.js).

I used this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/3303704 and I included this code in my app.js file:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

$.getScript("anotherfile.js", function(){
alert("Script loaded and executed.");
});

});
```

But Node.js returns me that "has no method 'getscript'".

Idea of the cause and solution? Thanks!

Comment: jQuery is a _client-side_ script.  Use `require()`.

Comment: That's a new one, haven't seen that before!

Comment: The answer you quoted has a different context. See the comments posted below that. Even if you manage to require jquery in node some things won't be there at node, e.g. alert which is part of browser DOM.

Comment: Thanks for these comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to use jQuery in node.

The solution you have linked to is a solution for front-end.

Use `require()` in node.

Try reading this article: [Node.js, Require and Exports](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/). It explains that for instance if you define this in one file called `user.js`:

```
var User = function(name, email) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
};
module.exports = User;
```

You can do this in another:

```
var user = require('./user');

var u = new user.User();
```